# How to return HTTP error code from servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have pages in my web application which are accessible only by the administrator. I wrote filter, but I don't understand how to return HTTP error code(403) from the filter if user isn't the admin.

```
public class AdminFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String username = servletRequest.getParameter("username");
        String password = servletRequest.getParameter("password");

        UserDao userDaoImpl = new UserDaoImpl();
        if(userDaoImpl.findByUsername(username).getPassword().equals(password)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } else {
            //respond with 403
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I can redirect to my custom 403 page but I'm wondering how to return HTTP error code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to cast `servletResponse` to `HttpServletResponse` first:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
```

Then use its `sendError()` method:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
```

`SC_FORBIDDEN` stands for code 403.

By the way, you don't *redirect* to 403 page, you just respond with that status. If you do that, the servlet container will serve a special 403 page to the user. You can configure that page in your `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error-403.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

This instructs the container to serve your custom page `/error-403.htm` when you set 403 status.

If you want a redirect, you could use `response.sendRedirect()` (it issues a 302 redirect).

Comment: I don't get the "don't redirect" part. What if I want custom 403 page with funny design? I need to respond with the status and have something that will respond to this status with the page?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clearify the situation with a 403 page with a funny design

Answer (score 4):

I have solved in this way:

```
((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
(HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "HMAC Failed - X-Authenticated-Id not available");
return;
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it by setting **401** as error code in the backend and catching the error in angular interceptor as below.

**Backend Java code:**

(HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

**Angular code:**

intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {

```
    return next.handle(req)
        .catch(error => {

            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status == 401) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/sessionExpired', { replaceUrl: true });

                return new EmptyObservable();
            }
            return _throw(error);
        });
}
```